# Password change was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, change-password

I can't change my password when I run my application.  It always stuck up on Validation Summary and I can't change my password.Is there something on the code that need to change or configuration is needed?  This is the error I receive.

> Password change was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.
>   The current password is incorrect or the new password is invalid.

But I am sure that I type my current password correctly.

**MODEL**
AccountModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace Customer.Models
{    
    public class ChangePasswordModel
    {
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Current password")]
        public string OldPassword { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "New password")]
        public string NewPassword { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm new password")]
        [Compare("NewPassword", ErrorMessage = "The new password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
// GET: /Account/ChangePassword
[Authorize]
public ActionResult ChangePassword()
{
    return View();
}

// POST: /Account/Register
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Attempt to register the user
        //MembershipCreateStatus createStatus;

        try
        {
            MembershipService.CreateUser(model.UserName, model.FullName, model.Password, model.Email);

            //if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
            //{
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false /* createPersistentCookie */);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            //}
        }
        catch(ArgumentException ae)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", ae.Message);
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}

// POST: /Account/ChangePassword
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ChangePassword(ChangePasswordModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // ChangePassword will throw an exception rather
        // than return false in certain failure scenarios.
        bool changePasswordSucceeded;

        try
        {
            MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name, true);
            changePasswordSucceeded = currentUser.ChangePassword(model.OldPassword, model.NewPassword);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            changePasswordSucceeded = false;
        }

        if (changePasswordSucceeded)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("ChangePasswordSuccess");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The current password is incorrect or the new password is invalid.");
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}


// GET: /Account/ChangePasswordSuccess
public ActionResult ChangePasswordSuccess()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: are there any exceptions? does the model come back as valid?

Comment: I can login on my apps,I can create,update user.But when I try to change my password usign that code I can't seem to change it.

Comment: @MapelCatalan You need to describe exactly what is happening, any errors?  Does ModelState.Isvalid = true/false?

Comment: @DanielA.White Comma "ModelState.IsValid" is not valid.

Comment: "ModelState.IsValid" is not valid.

Comment: @MapelCatalan Have you stepped through it with a debugger to find out if it really isn't valid?  It looks to me like it actually *is* valid because `The current password is incorrect or the new password is invalid.` is being added to the `ModelState`.  However, we can't see if it's throwing an exception or not because `changePasswordSucceeded` defaults to being `false`.  You need to step through that code and see whether an exception is being thrown, and if it is, check to see what type of exception it is and the error message it contains.  We can't help you without that.

Answer (score 1):

The validation is working just fine, thats why you get "The current password is incorrect or the new password is invalid." in your error report. Something is happening in your membership provider that is causing your flag to not be true... debug into this spot

```
changePasswordSucceeded = currentUser.ChangePassword(model.OldPassword, model.NewPassword);
```

Let me know what you find!